# How to remove unnecessary newlines from the_content()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the_content() in textarea. But it creates extra newlines. How do I get rid of them?

```
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" rows="8">
  <?php
  $content = $post->post_content;
  $content = preg_replace("/<embed?[^>]+>/i", "(embed) ", $content);
  $content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
  echo $content;
  ?>
</textarea>
```

Output screenshot is below
[image: Output Screenshot]

Screenshot with Console
[image: Output with console]

Comment: use `wp_kses` or add a filter to the content.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the extra new line you see? Did you try to move PHP tag to the same line with `<textarea>` tag?

```
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" rows="8"><?php
  $content = $post->post_content;
  $content = preg_replace("/<embed?[^>]+>/i", "(embed) ", $content);
  $content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
  echo $content;
?></textarea>
```

Comment: I see extra lines while the output is printed in textarea. Yes, I tried moving to one line, no change.

Comment: Can you update another screenshot with the HTML output?

Comment: I have posted the HTML output screenshot, please check